# Dynamic dispatch and generic interface factories

Tags: java, generics, factory, dispatch

How should I implement the `RequestFactory` interface in `Factory` such that I can create either `StringRequest` or `IntRequest` depending on what type is passed on?

In essence I want to create instances of concrete classes of a parametric abstract class dynamically, is this possible in Java?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer mInt = 10;
        String mString = "string";

        MyRequest mReq1 = new Factory<>(mString).getRequest();
        mReq1.PerformMyRequest();

        MyRequest mReq2 = new Factory<>(mInt).getRequest();
        mReq2.PerformMyRequest();
    }
}

class Factory<T> implements RequestFactory<T> {

    private final MyRequest<T> Req;

    public Factory(T body) {
        Req = create(body);
    }

    public MyRequest<T> getRequest() {
        return Req;
    }

    @Override
    // How do I implement the interface here so
    // that correct factory is invoked depending on T
    // so that I can return either StringRequest or IntRequest
    public MyRequest<T> create(T body) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

#### Factory Interface:

```
// Interface
interface RequestFactory<T> {
    MyRequest<T> create(T body);
}
// Concrete specialized factories
class StringFactory implements RequestFactory<String> {
    @Override
    public StringRequest create(String body) {
        return new StringRequest(body);
    }
}
class IntFactory implements RequestFactory<Integer> {
    @Override
    public IntRequest create(Integer body) {
        return new IntRequest(body);
    }
}
```

#### Generic abstract class with its two concrete children

```
// ======================================================

// AbstractClass
abstract class MyRequest<T> {
    T mVal;

    MyRequest(T body) {
        mVal = body;
    }

    public void PerformMyRequest() {
        System.out.println("-> From abstract: " + mVal);

    }

}
// Concrete classes that I'd like to automatically
// create using the factory above
class StringRequest extends MyRequest<String> {

    StringRequest(String body) {
        super(body);
    }

    public void PerformMyRequest() {
        super.PerformMyRequest();
        System.out.println("  -> From StringRequest");
    }
}
class IntRequest extends MyRequest<Integer> {

    IntRequest(Integer body) {
        super(body);
    }

    public void PerformMyRequest() {
        super.PerformMyRequest();
        System.out.println("  -> From IntRequest");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done by java. You can accomplish this by writing a "MetaFactory" (i.e. a factory of factories) which does type checking to choose the factory implementation to create and return.

```
public final class RequestMetaFactory {

  public RequestFactory<T> newFactory(T req) {
    if (req instanceof String) {
      return new StringRequestFactory((String)req);
    }

    if (req instanceof Integer) {
      return new IntegerRequestFactory((Integer)req);
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException(req.getClass() + " not a supported arg type");
  }

}
```

This could be made more sophisticated by doing an SPI lookup to find actual RequestFactory instances and asking each what type they support.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, generic types are only intended for compile-time type checking, and are generally not available at runtime. This means that you can't make any runtime decisions based on `T` in your `create`-method.

You also can't just make the jump from knowing that you want a `RequestFactory<String>` to knowing that "the" concrete implementation for this purpose is the `StringFactory`. There could be other classes which also extend `RequestFactory<String>`, so you will have to explicitly state somewhere that `StringFactory` is what you want. If this was C++, you could write template specializations to say "this is *the* implementation for a `RequestFactory<String>`", but this is not possible with generics.

Brett Okken already pointed out one possible alternative solution which is very similar to what I had written, so I'll just point to his answer for that.

Comment: Having C++ background I obsessed over doing this for 2 days, should have asked earlier :) Thanks.